# Ignoring content with the Drupal 6 search module

Tags: search, drupal-6

I have some content that I do not want the Drupal search module to index:
for example, I do not want drupal search module to search my webform data.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with the Search Restrict module.
http://drupal.org/project/search_restrict

Be aware (in D6) things will still be indexed, and at least one role must be able to search everything, so you'll need an admin role.

If you're still on D5, this module actually excludes content types form the search system entirely.
http://drupal.org/project/search_block

If you really want to get fancy and create different search routes check out Finder.